Business verification issue for my facebook app
I have an issue similar to that discussed in this thread (facebook login doesn't work). I'm creating a new one because my app looks a bit different, so neither of the given solutions helped me. Facebook explicitly tells me to verify my business (required action):


After that I'm being redirected to https://business.facebook.com/settings/security/ page, which tells me, that my organization doesn't require businsess verification, which creates an infinite loop of desperation:

Maybe someone faced a similar issue?
